# trying to convert java code to kotlin in Android studio flamingo

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio-flamingo

hope you are in good health
would not take much time.
I am working on windows 10 x64
i am making a login/logup page with firebase in flamingo  2022.2.1 Patch 2 , but the tutorial im followiing is using java in a section to which I named as Register(have uploaded its picture)
if anyone could help me finding a right tutorial or can tell me how can i translate the code in kotlin. what i hv strive is mentioned in the next section
thanks very much

[image: image displaying java code]
[image: image displaying "register section "]

i have tried using online converter but can't trust it coz maybe it has some flaws.
i have tried finding video tutorial on flamingo but cant find much, maybe i have to search more

Comment: If you paste java code in a kotlin file in Android Studio it should offer to convert it automatically. Also, what's wrong with online convertors? Why can't you trust it? Just see if the outcome makes sense to you and adjust if necessary. And you know you don't actually have to use kotlin. If you want you can use java just fine

Comment: Thanks very much brother, I will definitely do conversion , apart from that as you have mentioned, java code will be automatically convert, but why is so that my current register.kt file is not converting java code and gives a red underline,

Comment: please include the code not within image but with appropriate format thanks

Answer (score 1):

Converting .java file to kotlin (.kt) file *( I am using Android Studio Flamingo )*

- Goto top bar in Android Studio
- Click or open java file you want to convert
- Select **Code** ->Select **Convert java file to kotlin** *OR click java file and press* **Ctrl+Alt+Shift+K** *to convert* [image: Here is the screenshot]
- After converting to kotlin file, you will encounter errors while referencing UI component in kotlin.
- You need to reference views as below

Code Snippet:

```
class RegisterActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

override 
fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)

    val email: EditText= findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail)
    val pass: EditText= findViewById(R.id.editTextPass)
    val register: Button= findViewById(R.id.register)

    register.setOnClickListener {  }

    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: lemme check if it works